Next Auth Credential Provider
I am pretty new to next js and next Auth and I am trying to wrap my head around how it all works. In my scenario, we already backend in .net running on Azure. I have a front end in react, but we potentially want to explore the option of moving towards next js. I was trying to get the credential provider working for authentication. So in my scenario, I make an axios call to the azure and that gives me all the refresh tokens,access tokens etc that I need to further use for all my request. From my understanding of the docs, the next auth app route manages the jwt tokens when a user logs. So how do I get the use the tokens sent from my azure to work? have I got the concept wrong. Please help! This is my code
export const authProviders: NextAuthOptions = {
providers: [
GoogleProvider({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID!,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
}),
CredentialsProvider({
  name: "Credentials",
  credentials: {
    username: {
      label: "Username",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "user",
      value: "Administrator",
    },
    password: {
      label: "Password",
      type: "password",
      placeholder: "pass",
      value: "password",
    },
  },
  async authorize(credentials, req) {
    if (!credentials || !credentials?.username || !credentials?.password) {
      return null;
    }
 try {
      const { data, cookies } = await createBrowserToken(
        credentials.username,
        credentials.password
      );

      if (data) {
        console.log("response for tokens", data);
        const { access_token, refresh_token, expires_in, endpoint_tokens } =
          data;
        const getUserToken = endpoint_tokens.find(
          (token: any) => token.endpoint_route === "GETapi/v1/Users/GetUser"
        ).access_token;
        console.log(
          "response tokensss",
          getUserToken,
          access_token,
          cookies
        );
        if (cookies !== null) {
          const user = await fetchUser(getUserToken, access_token, cookies);
          console.log("user", user);
          if (user) {
            return {
              id: user.id,
              name: `${user.firstName}-${user.lastName}`,
              email: user.email,
            };
          } else return null;
        }
        return null;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error);
      return null;
    }

I need to send these endpoint tokens and access token every time when I make the call to azure backend. I need to store these tokens in the localstorage so they can be persisted and used. But because I am on the server side I am not able to. Can I manipulate the session to hold all these tokens?

From this post
you fetch the jwt inside authorize function. this is its type:
authorize: (
    credentials: Record<keyof C, string> | undefined,
    req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">
  ) => Awaitable<User | null>
}

whatever you return from here is passed to the jwt. From the post's code:
async authorize(credentials, req) {
        
        try {
          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          });

          if (!res.ok) {
            // credentials are invalid
            return null;
          }

          const parsedResponse = await res.json();

          // accessing the jwt returned by server
          const jwt = parsedResponse.access_token;

// You can make more request to get other information about the user eg. Profile details

         // return user credentials together with jwt
          return {
            ...credentials,
            jwt,
          };
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
      },



To make sure our JWT is included in the session object, we have to add
it to the JWT in the session explicitly.

export const authOptions = {
providers:[...],
callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
     // user is only available the first time a user signs in authorized
      if (user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          jwt: user.jwt,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.jwt = token.jwt;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
}

Attaching JWT to each request dynamically (using Axios)

Axios interceptors are a great way to add more items to the request
before it gets sent.
To create an Axios interceptor, we need to:
Create an Axios instance Create the interceptor to attach the JWT to
every request before it is sent

import axios from "axios";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

// Create a new Axios instance
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/", // Replace with your backend server's base URL
});

// Create the interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
  // Get the session
  const session = await getSession();

  // Add your desired session value to the request headers
  if (session) {
    request.headers = {
      ...request.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session.jwt}`,
    };
  }

  return request;
});

export const BackendInstance = axiosInstance;

